# How to display discount on Special price in product detail page?

Tags: magento2, product, product-view, special-price

I overridden module-catalog/product/price/amount/default.phtml file in my theme

```
<?php 
    echo $this->helper('Test\ProductDetail\Helper\Data')->DisplayDiscountLabel($_product);
?>
```

In helper file I have following code ;

```
 namespace Test\ProductDetail\Helper;


 class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
public function DisplayDiscountLabel($_product)
{
   $originalPrice = $_product->getPrice();
    $finalPrice = $_product->getFinalPrice();

    $percentage = 0;
    if ($originalPrice > $finalPrice) {
        $percentage = number_format(($originalPrice - $finalPrice) * 100 / $originalPrice,0);
    }

    if ($percentage) {
        return "(".$percentage."%)";
    }

   }
}
```

but problem is that in phtml file I am not getting value of **$_product**?

Comment: Where you want to display the percentage in the page ? Do you want to be in a particular place?

Comment: @St3phan I want to display discount on product detail page where price is displayed.

Answer (score 2):

In overrrided phtml file

```
../app/design/frontend/[VENDOR]/[THEME]/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/price/amount/default.phtml
```

You can get product object in a variable **$_product** Using

```
<?php   $_product = $block->getSaleableItem(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below in phtml file

```
    $objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
    $_product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($_product->getId());
```

Comment: Getting errro - $_product->getId() -- undefined variable: _product in